# Dúvida sobre o uso da palavra "vossa"

Tags: gramática

Tenho ouvido dizer que o uso da palavra "vossa" é para o plural da palavra "tua". Surgem-me, então, dúvidas sobre o uso desta palavra.
Afinal, é ou não certo dizer-se "vossa excelência", "vossa mercê" e "vossa pessoa" quando se está a querer prestar referência a apenas uma pessoa? Não seria a forma correcta, nestes casos, dizer-se no singular "tua excelência", "tua mercê" e "tua pessoa"?

Comment: renanlinux não é o caso de escandalizar ninguém, os sites da rede Stack Exchange têm por norma não utilizar saudações para manter o foco na dúvida, além disso, segundo os CM's tem também um mecanismo que limpa saudações automaticamente.

Comment: renanlinux dá uma olhada na [ajuda do site](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) na parte que diz ***Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.***

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu evitaria substituir _correcta_ por _correta_, etc., a não ser que o resto da pergunta seguisse as convenções do AO1990. Afinal de contas, o acordo não está em vigor em muitos países lusófonos, como Angola e Moçambique.

Comment: @Artefacto tens toda a razão, de qualquer forma já foi revertida a edição.

Answer (score 7):

É preciso não confundir a **pessoa semântica** dos pronomes, i.e., quem designam no discursos (falante, ouvinte, ou terceiros, respetivamente para a 1.ª, 2.ª ou 3.ª pessoas) com a **pessoa gramatical**, que é apenas de natureza morfossintática, e não coincide necessariamente com a pessoa semântica. *Vossa Excelência*, *Vossa Mercê*, tal como *você* e a *a gente*, constituem formas de tratamento; são pronomes ou locuções pronominais em que a pessoa semântica não coincide com a pessoa gramatical, já que todas elas levam o verbo para 3.ª (com a ressalva de que, durante alguns séculos, o tratamento por *Vossa Excelência* fez alternar pronomes e desinências verbais da 2.ª e 3.ª pessoas). Vê: *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, pág. 899-900.

Em particular, o motivo por que se usa *Vossa Excelência* em lugar de *Tua Excelência*, prende-se com a forma que a [distinção T-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) tomava nas primeiras fases da língua (*Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguêsa*, M. Said Ali, edição de 1964, ortografia original):

> 416. Do latim vieram os pronomes *tu* e *vós* como tratamento direto de pessoa ou pessoas a quem se dirigia a palavra. Tornando-se *tu* insuficiente para expressar o sentimento de humildade e respeito, recorreu-se ao tratamento indireto. Por um dos expedientes, o mais antigo em linguagem portuguêsa, o atrevimento de vir perante um indivíduo de hierarquia superior, e olhar para êle face a face, se disfarçou fingindo repartida a vista pelo seu cortejo ou nimbo, real ou imaginário. Desta atenção, com que se magnificava e lisonjeava a pessoa única, se originou o costume de empregar o plural *vós*, em vez do pronome singular, como simples prova de respeito e polidez, depois de apagada da memória a imagem da situação primitiva.
> 417. Outro modo de tratamento indireto consistiu em fingir que se dirigia a palavra a um atributo ou qualidade eminente da pessoa de categoria superior, e não a ela própria. Assim, aproximavam-se os vassalos de seu rei com o tratamento de *vossa mercê*, *vossa senhoria*, substituído depois por *vossa alteza* e finalmente por *vossa majestade*; assim usou-se o tratamento ducal de *vossa excelência* e adotaram-se na hierarquia eclesiástica *vossa reverência*, *vossa paternidade*, *vossa eminência*, *vossa santidade*.

Comment: Obrigado pelo suporte! Não chega a ser o caso de, se se disser a um presidente de república, como prestando referência a ele, tú, seja falta de boa educação, correcto? Pois que, em dicionários de língua portuguesa, a palavra "tú", de maneira nenhuma é ofensa. Lembro-me de livros, em que pessoas se referem a reis, dizendo: "Tu". Quanto aos reis, não deixaram de tratar a estas pessoas, pacificamente, dentro de leis. Até mesmo a Deus, que é pregado no monoteísmo, como O mais Perfeito, dentre nós, é dito-lhe, "Tú".

Comment: @renanlinux Referires-te ao Presidente da República por_tu_ seria sem sombra de dúvida falta de educação (a não ser que fosses amigo dele e te estivesses a dirigir a ele nessa capacidade). A forma de tratamento convencial para o Presidente da República) é _Vossa Excelência_.

Comment: Isso deve ser coisa da atualidade, isso não consta em livros antigos que eu já tenha visto.

Comment: @renanlinux Não, não é recente. A distinção TV entre _tu_ e _vós_ (este úiltimo mais tarde substituído por outros pronomes ou locuções) é muito antiga na língua. Repara que o mesmo aconteceu noutras línguas (inglês, _ye_ / _you_ por _thou_, francês, _vous_ por _tu_, etc.)